# Select only Value Length & Format - MySQL

Tags: mysql, unique, string-formatting, maxlength

Is there a way to select only fields that meet the following criteria from a specific column in mysql:

MAX Length = 9
First 3 characters must be HSA
Last 6 characters must only be INT
The 6 digits must start with 0... This may change later to start with 1 / 2 etc.

The below table shows the basic schema and possible fields values.

```
row | visit_date | field_value 
----+------------+--------------- 
1   |2016-12-07  |HSA023456   
2   |2016-12-08  |HSA059870 
3   |2016-12-06  |225981450    
4   |2016-12-05  |HSAB02354    
5   |2016-12-13  |HSA0234567   
6   |2016-12-14  |HSA    
7   |2016-12-14  |HSA0987    
8   |2016-12-16  |1234HSA00
```

Rows 1 - 3 are valid rows and would have to be returned.

Rows 4 - 8 are invalid rows and will have to be igonred.

I have tried the below, although this does not provide the correct result as it only provide a partial solution:

```
,       CASE
            WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(NFB.field_value) > 8 AND NFB.field_value LIKE 'HSA%' THEN UPPER(NFB.field_value)
            WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(NFB.field_value) < 9 AND NFB.field_value LIKE 'HSA%' THEN CONCAT(UPPER(NFB.field_value),'VALIDATE')
```

ELSE ""
            END field_value

Thanks

Comment: Please add some schema SQL, some dummy data, what you've tried and some sample results of your desired output.

Comment: Yes, try it for your self. And perhaps take a look at the dark art of regular expressions

Comment: First 4 are "HSA0", right?

Comment: Correct, however the HSA0, may in the next month or 2 become HSA1. The HSA is the only part that won't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is a good candidate for using MySQL's regex operator `REGEXP`.  Note that all your requirements can be met by matching with the following regex:

```
^HSA0[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

This matches 9 characters exactly, which begin with `HSA0` followed by any other five digits.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE field_value REGEXP '^HSA0[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
```

**Update:**

If you want to restrict to only uppercase, then you could add a `LIKE` condition checking for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE field_value REGEXP '^HSA0[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' AND
      field_value LIKE BINARY 'HSA%'
```

`REGEXP` is case insensitive, so a workaround is required.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks... Does the REGXP also then only accept the HSA as an upper case value? Sorry this is one part I left out of my original question, but when looking at the result set I realised that I need to also exclude lower case hsa to ensure a better quality of data.

Comment: THanks a million, appreciate it. Looking at the solution, does the BINARY operator then look for an exact match to the like field? 

i.e if I had to in future say LIKE BINARY 'Hsa%' the uppercase and lower case checks would apply here? (This is just a hypothetical scenario for my learning)

Comment: Yes, using `BINARY` with `LIKE` will force a case sensitive comparison.  In this case, you wanted all caps.

Comment: Thank you :-)... Now I have learnt two very, very valuable lessons.

Answer (score 1):

you can select the rows where your condtion are true

```
  select my_col
  from my_table
  where left(my_col, 3) = 'HSA'
  AND right(my_col,6) REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
  AND left(right(my_col,6),1) ='0';
```

or

```
  select my_col
  from my_table
  where left(my_col, 3) = 'HSA0'
  AND right(my_col,6) REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: Thanks :-)... This answer also helps a lot here and is also a very valid solution